# How to pass an array to a function to use it in a query with the IN operator

Tags: postgresql

I want to pass an array to a Postgres function to use in an `IN` clause.

```
An error occurred executing the SQL command:
SELECT *
  FROM
      get_invtransferences_porders_fporders (300001300 , variadic array [ 300093753 , 300094126 , 300093349 , 300093838 , 300094128 ] ...
```

But I shows me this error:

> ```
> ERROR: operator does not exist : integer = integer [ ]
> Hint : No operator matches the name and type of arguments. You may need to add explicit type conversions .
> Where : PL / pgSQL get_invtransferences_porders_fporders (numeric , integer []) function on line 8 FOR loop around rows of a
> ```
>
> SELECT

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_invtransferences_porders_fporders(p_product_id numeric, VARIADIC P_INVTRANSFERENCES_IDS int[])
  RETURNS SETOF record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
DECLARE
    PORDER_PRODUCT RECORD;
    COMPONENT RECORD;
    COMPONENT2 RECORD;
    COMPONENT3 RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR PORDER_PRODUCT IN (
                      SELECT 
                        'porder'                                                    AS "operation_type"
                        ,porders.id                                                 AS "porder_id"
                        ,porders.user_id                                            AS "porder_user_id"
                        ,(SELECT name FROM users WHERE users.id = porders.user_id)  AS "porder_user_name"
                        ,porders.delivery_datetime                                  AS "porder_delivery_datetime"
                        ,porders_products.requested                                 AS "product_requested"
                        ,porders_products.produced                                  AS "product_produced"
                        ,products.code                                              AS "product_code"
                        ,products.NAME                                              AS "product_name"
                        ,(
                          SELECT products.name
                          FROM products
                          WHERE id = product_components.component_product_id
                          )                                                         AS "component_product_name"
                        ,product_components.quantity                                AS "component_quantity"
                        ,(
                          SELECT products.um_id
                          FROM products
                          WHERE id = product_components.component_product_id
                          )                                                         AS "component_um_id"
                        ,(product_components.quantity / products.production_base) * porders_products.requested  AS "total"
                      FROM porders
                        ,porders_products
                        ,products
                        ,product_components
                      WHERE porders.id = porders_products.porder_id
                        AND porders_products.product_id = products.id
                        AND porders_products.product_id = product_components.product_id
                        AND porders.id IN (
                          SELECT rawm_audit_porders.porder_id
                          FROM rawm_audit_invtransferences
                            ,rawm_audits
                            ,rawm_audit_porders
                          WHERE rawm_audit_invtransferences.rawm_audits_id = rawm_audits.id
                            AND rawm_audit_porders.rawm_audits_id = rawm_audits.id
                            AND rawm_audit_invtransferences.invtransference_id IN
                            (
                              SELECT 
                                invtransferences.id
                              FROM invtransferences
                                ,invtransferences_products
                                ,products
                              WHERE invtransferences.id = invtransferences_products.invtransference_id
                                AND products.id = invtransferences_products.product_id
                                AND invtransferences.id IN (P_INVTRANSFERENCES_IDS)
                            )
                          )
                        AND product_components.component_product_id = p_product_id
                 ) LOOP
        IF(PORDER_PRODUCT.porder_id IS NOT NULL)THEN
            RETURN NEXT PORDER_PRODUCT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;         
END;
$body$     VOLATILE COST 100 ROWS 1000
```

I think the error is here: `invtransferences.id IN (P_INVTRANSFERENCES_IDS)`

This is the select that calls the function:

```
SELECT  
      *
  FROM 
      get_invtransferences_porders_fporders(300001300 , VARIADIC array[300093753, 300094126, 300093349, 300093838, 300094128] )
  AS
  (
       "operation_type" varchar,
       "porder_id" numeric,
       "porder_user_id" numeric,
       "porder_user_name" varchar,
       "porder_delivery_datetime" date,
       "product_requested" numeric,
       "product_produced" numeric,
       "product_code" varchar,
       "product_name" varchar,
       "component_product_name" varchar,
       "component_quantity" numeric,
       "component_um_id" varchar,
       "total" numeric
   )
  ORDER BY
      "porder_id";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the `IN` list, use the `=ANY` syntax, which deals directly with arrays rather than lists:

```
create function foo(int[]) returns bigint as $$ 
    select sum(abalance) from pgbench_accounts where aid =ANY($1) 
$$ language sql;
```